# Electron crashes after ODBC connection

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, electron

When I have retrieved the date with an ODBC connection, the data is retrieved. Then when I first went to another page and come back to refresh the data again I get an error message like the one below.

Code as the data is retrieved:

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
const odbc = require("odbc");

async function queryOData() {
  const connection = await odbc.connect(
    `DSN=odbc605;Description=odbc605;UID=odbc605;;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=ZB585;DATABASE=605;LANGUAGE=Nederlands;StatsLog_On=Yes;StatsLogFile=C:\Users\FLORS\Desktop\STATS.LOG;`
  );
  const data = await connection.query(
    "SELECT TOP 100 DT_ItemsTabel.ItemCode, DT_ItemsTabel.Description FROM DT_ItemsTabel"
  );
  alert(data);
}

queryOData();
```

ERROR:

```
[17028:0310/140004.528:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(844)] not connected
[11116:0310/140122.300:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Electron index.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require("electron-squirrel-startup")) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    //width: 800,
    //height: 500,
    icon: __dirname + "/assets/ZB-icon.ico",
    webPreferences: {
      //preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools: true,
      webSecurity: false,
      backgroundThrottling: false,
    },
    autoHideMenuBar: false,
    backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3",
  });
};
```

I don't expect to get an error anymore.

Comment: your connection string looks a bit off, have you testet it in the microsoft odbc datasource administration